# for() loop fails to stop looping ?

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to print an array until it's empty. 
Here is my code:

```
for ($i=0; $array[0][$i]!=NULL; ++$i){
echo $array[0][$i];
}
```

However it looks like it performs the echo one extra time, I don't know why ? 
Here's my output for an array that contains data up to array[0][2]. 
I am sure that array[0][3] is empty, I tried it with `if(array[0][3]==NULL)`

```
Test 0
Test 1
Test 2
( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\... on line 9
```

Any idea ?

Comment: it means that `$array[0][3]` doesn't exist

Comment: Perhaps you should use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) instead?  A variable set to NULL can still exist.

Comment: What do you mean by "array[0][3] is empty"? What value did you store in that location? How did you get it there? PHP doesn't automatically give NULLs for array elements that don't exist at all.

Comment: The array comes from a preg_match_all but i'll just use the foreach function ;) ty

Answer (score 0):

You should use the arrays length when you loop... Or try this instead:

```
foreach($array[0] as $val) {
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: Works, ty :). 
I still don't get why mine didn't work, but meh

Comment: If you try to access a value in the array that doesn't exist, an error will be thrown... In your case you tried to access index 3 of the array which didn't exist, therefore an error was thrown. As suggested, instead of comparing NULL you could've used isset. But these approaches are not very common. Rather use `sizeof($array[0])` and compare it to $i, or simply use the foreach loop as I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's throwing an error is because an array index that does not exist is not equal to NULL. You can modify your code to this:

```
for ($i=0; isset($array[0][$i]); ++$i){
  echo $array[0][$i];
}
```

Or try this instead:

```
$ctr = count($array[0]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $ctr; $i++) {
    echo $array[0][$i];
}
```

The loop should finish after reaching the end of the array.

Comment: Actually: `ini_set('display_errors'); $foo = []; var_dump($foo['hello']);` will yield `NULL`: unset variables always equal NULL in PHP.

Comment: @BerryLangerak yeah you are correct on this. But PHP does not seem to recognize that an undefined index is = NULL so it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

It makes perfect sense, really. PHP can not magically know that the next id (in your example, index number '3') is not set, it has to access the variable to determine that. That's also why you get the notice.

In short, it does not execute the body of the for loop, but it has to execute the test to determine whether or not to continue.

Anyway, use a `foreach` loop, or calculate the number of items in the array first and increment `$i` till they match.

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternatives to you code that should actually work.

```
foreach($array[0] as $val)
    if($val===null)
        break;
    else
        echo $val;
```

or

```
$arrlen=count($array[0]);
for($i=0;$i<$arrlen;$i++)
    if($array[0][$i]===null)
        break;
    else
        echo $array[0][$i];
```

or even

```
$i=0;
while($array[0][$i]!==null) { //not recommended, can cause infinite loop
   echo $array[0][$i];
   $i++;
}
```